# Value is not updated on cell of Table View after editing

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

**Value is not updated on cell of Table View after editing**
I've used java to write program. I tried to edit cell of table view but It was not updated after key released. 
Here is this case when  I want to edit any cell at Tour No. Column

[image: Open here to see table view]

Main class

```
 ObservableList<Tours> tourdata=FXCollections.observableArrayList();                                                                                                           
 public void Halongbay()
         {
               TableView<Tours> table = new TableView<Tours>();
               table.setEditable(true);
               // Tạo cột ProjectID (Kiểu dữ liệu String)   
               TableColumn<Tours, String> hotelCol = new TableColumn<Tours, String>("Hotel");
               TableColumn<Tours, String> priceCol = new TableColumn<Tours, String>("Price per Day ");
               TableColumn<Tours, String> tournumberCol = new TableColumn<Tours, String>("Tour No.");

               hotelCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("hotelname"));
               priceCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
               tournumberCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("tournumber"));


               tournumberCol.setEditable(true);
               tournumberCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Tours>forTableColumn());

               tournumberCol.setOnEditCommit(
                (TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Tours, String> t) ->
                (t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setTournumber(t.getNewValue()));
               table.getColumns().addAll(hotelCol,priceCol,tournumberCol);

               String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+BuildIP+":"+TCP+";instance="+Instancename+";databaseName="+Db+";user="+UID+";password="+PSW+"";
               Connection con = null;  
               PreparedStatement stmt = null;  
               ResultSet rs = null;

                 try{
                     con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
                     String sql = "SELECT *from INFOR ";
                       stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                       rs=stmt.executeQuery();
                   while(rs.next()) {
                       tourdata.add(new Tours
                                    (rs.getString(1),
                                     rs.getString(2),
                                     "10"
                                        ));
                       table.setItems(tourdata);    
                                    }
                       stmt.close();
                       rs.close();
                    }
                   catch(Exception ex){System.err.println(ex);}

           VBox root = new VBox();
           root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
           root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            root.setSpacing(20);

           root.getChildren().addAll(table);
           Stage stage = new Stage();
           stage.setTitle("Tourist information");

           Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 500);
           stage.setScene(scene);
           stage.show();
         }
```

Tours Class

```
public class Tours {
private String hotelname;
private String price;
private String tournumber;
public Tours(String hotelname, String price, String tournumber) {
    super();
    this.hotelname = hotelname;
    this.price = price;
    this.tournumber = tournumber;
}
public String getHotelname() {
    return hotelname;
}
public void setHotelname(String hotelname) {
    this.hotelname = hotelname;
}
public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public String getTournumber() {
    return tournumber;
}
public void setTournumber(String tournumber) {
    this.tournumber = tournumber;
}
```

I expect any cell at Tour No. can be edited and show new value on table view.
Thanks for help

Comment: @alexvaluiskyi no ... whatever the problem, refresh is not the correct solution (with a probability to extremely near to 1)!

Comment: hmm ... why do you expect the value to be updated on keyReleased? Edit, press enter and the value is committed.

Comment: @kleopatra  It seems you had solution for this challenge ? Could you help me with some code in detail. I really appreciate your help

Comment: your code works as expected .. (the only modification was to move the setup into the apps start method and replace the database access with hard-coded values - which you should have done to make it more easily reproducible :)

Comment: sry, don't understand what you mean .. your while loop looks (and should be)! unrelated to the editing. Anyway, don't call setItems in the loop: instead, collect the data, then set the items when all are collected. And please fix the formatting (while making it a [mcve] to ensure that what you show us is really what is misbehaving and not some snippet produced on-the-fly), it's extremely hard to read

Comment: @kleopatra  Thank you for your suggestion . Ok I'm gonna left the thought of Key released event to update new data  And I should consider to Press Enter :)